# How to extract only certain tags from HTML document using PHP?

Tags: php, xpath, tags, store, web-crawler

I'm using a crawler to retrieve the HTML content of certain pages on the web. I currently have the entire HTML stored in a single PHP variable:

```
$string = "<PRE>".htmlspecialchars($crawler->results)."</PRE>\n";
```

What I want to do is select all "p" tags (for example) and store their in an array. What is the proper way to do that?

I've tried the following, by using xpath, but it doesn't show anything (most probably because the document itself isn't an XML, I just copy-pasted the example given in its documentation).

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement ($string);

    $result=$xml->xpath('/p');
    while(list( , $node)=each($result)){
        echo '/p: ' , $node, "\n"; 
    }
```

Hopefully someone with (a lot) more experience in PHP will be able to help me out :D

Comment: This may help you out: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks a lot! That looks like a really solid and elegant solution. Will look into it right away!

Comment: No problem. Although not perfect, it seems to work most of the time.

Comment: It does work pretty nice. However, it doesn't retrieve p tags...I don't know what exactly I'm doing wrong, I'm just replacing a with p in foreach($html->find('p') as $e) ...

Comment: It grabs the entire document, then parses it. See the full documentation for the details: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

Comment: also, make sure you're doing something with it once you `find` it. You need to `echo` our do something with it

Comment: Got it working! Thanks a million. I was just missing the obvious (it's 3 A.M. over here right now and I'm more than a bit sleepy). If you'll post this as an answer, I'd like to accept it. It's the best version I got so far.

Comment: Glad to hear it. I've been up at 3AM MANY times and I know how it feels. :) Answer posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Simple HTML Dom. It will grab external pages and process them with fairly accurate detail.

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

It can be used like this:

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all images
foreach($html->find('img') as $element)
   echo $element->src . '<br>';
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) along with [DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php). The workflow should be quite simple. Something like:

```
$doc = DOMDocument::loadHTML(htmlspecialchars($crawler->results));
$pNodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('p');
```

Which will return a DOMNodeList.

Answer (score 2):

I vote for use regexp. For tag p

```
preg_match_all('/<p>(.*)<\/p>/', '<p>foo</p><p>foo 1</p><p>foo 2</p>', $arr, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
if(is_array($arr))
{
 foreach($arr as $value)
 {
   echo $value."</br>";
 }
}
```

Comment: I was writing the same, and I would add that using an XML reader for reading HTML documents is not safe. Not half of the HTML on the web is properly formed as XML...

Comment: Yeap...I'm discovering that as we speak. Thanks for your time...I'll try your solution in a sec and get back to you..

Comment: If you're concerned about well-formed HTML, do check out the documentation on DOMDocument. Its loadHTML method doesn't require the HTML to be perfectly formed and it provides a whole lot of convenience.